# How to send POST data with postman? (regular form, with key's value is a json string)

Tags: postman

I am playing with a web app, which url is: https://yunjing.ichunqiu.com/cve/detail/912?pay=1

and found that the form is a regular form , with 1 field: `string`, which accepts json string.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However, I found using postman I could not send request successfully ( server shows the request parameter is null )

and I spent nearly an hour and finall switch to use Ruby code like this, and successful:

```
require 'httparty'

require 'csv'

url = 'http://eci-2zeh7w42wau8pti7ijd3.cloudeci1.ichunqiu.com:8080/fastjson'
response = HTTParty.post url, body: {
  string: %Q{{"name": "jim"}}
puts response.inspect
```

and got success response:

```
bundle exec ruby scripts/test_fastjson.rb
#<HTTParty::Response:0x26908 parsed_response="
<html><h2>Your input is: </h2>
  {\"name\": \"jim\"}<br/>
  {\"name\":\"jim\"}<br/>
</html>\n", 
@response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, 
@headers={"date"=>["Mon, 01 May 2023 07:19:41 GMT"], 
"content-length"=>["77"], "connection"=>["close"]}>
```

I have been using POSTMAN for years, any one could figure out why the POSTMAN can not send the correct parameter to server? thanks a lot.

( I checked that server host, port are correct )
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xzh1.png